# How do I make this event handler more flexible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function I've written to do live calculation based on user input. It works well but I'm wondering if there is a more scalable solution. Every time I have a new equation to run that needs the same functionality (live updating), I end up copying the script, changing the equation variables. Obviously the equation is the same then I will just use the same function request.

Let me know if there is a better way or if I'm approaching it right.

http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/zhow0uky/

```
var formCalc = function (input, multiplier, output) {
  var reloadCalc = function () {
  var formula = parseFloat($(input).val()) * parseFloat($(multiplier).val());
  $(output).val(formula.toFixed(0));    
  };
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(input).on("keyup", function () {
       reloadCalc();
    });
    $(input).trigger("keyup");     
  });
};

formCalc('.input', '.multiplier', '.output');
```

### Unscalable parts of the code

**Variables**

`(input, multiplier, output)`

**Decimal Places**

`.toFixed(0)`

**Formula**

`var formula = parseFloat($(input).val()) * parseFloat($(multiplier).val());`

Comment: HAve you considered storing the formula within the data attributes on your input elements? Are you looking to make the number of inputs also dynamic?

Comment: For user input it will come from the value. The output either goes into another input for submission or to an HTML element for pure print out and read only.

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/zhow0uky/4/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an argument `reloadCalc`:

```
var formCalc = function (input, output, reloadCalc) {
  input.on("keyup", function() {
    output.val(reloadCalc(input.val()));
  }).trigger("keyup");
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  formCalc($('.input'), $('.output'), function(input) {
    return (parseFloat(input) * parseFloat($('.multiplier').val()).toFixed(0);
  });
  //...other formCalc calls
});
```

Now, given you have an input element `$('#in')`, output element `$('#out')`, and function `f(input)` you can simply do:

```
formCalc($('#in'), $('#out'), f);
```

Comment: I wanted to write exactly the same, but i was slow... :)
I think this is the best solution for this problem!

Comment: I like this. Is there any issue putting like 40 calcs inside that one function?

Comment: If you want to use this more than once, define the formula once (or just define the versions you want) and use them as the third param.
(I mean don't copy the whole call with the anonime function.)
It'll work perfectly with multiple formCalc calls.

Comment: @dvoutt if you mean the `$(document).ready`, yes you can put as many as you want. In fact, you should ideally only have 1 `$(document).ready` call.

Comment: No I meant the formula part. I will be running multiple different formulas. Was curious if there would be any performance issues. But I wrote that when I was reading the script on my phone and saw the structure differently than it was written so I retract my statement :)

Comment: Ran into a bit of a snap, I can't get the change to happen when the multiplier changes (many of my inputs have multiple elements changing).

Comment: @dvoutt Your question didn't show any indication that the value was to be recalculated when the multiplier changes. If you're having problems, ask a new question with the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Make the formula a function that gets passed in to formCalc. The inputs can then be passed in to the formula with .apply(), which allows you to have any number of inputs. In this example, we can multiply the first two inputs with a variable precision:

```
var formCalc = function (formula, inputSelector, output) {
    //Cache the set of input elements,
    //which will be in document order
    var inputs = $(inputSelector);

    var reloadCalc = function () {
        //Parse every input to a float
        var values = $.map(inputs, function(el) {
           return parseFloat($(el).val());
        });
        //Then pass the resulting array to the formula
        var result = formula.apply(this, values);
        $(output).val(result);
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        inputs.on("keyup", function () {
            reloadCalc();
        });
        reloadCalc();
    });
};

//The formula can tak an arbitrary array of arguments,
//which you can do anything with
var multiplyWithPrecision = function(a, b, precision) {
    return (a * b).toFixed(precision);
}

formCalc(multiplyWithPrecision, '.input','.output');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/f9s02zgo/1/